# Why a statement written after iterating over an empty list does not work python

Tags: python, for-loop

To my knowledge, the following code will not work:

```
empty_list = []
if empty_list:
    print("It's an empty list, duh...")
```

However, I came across the following situation:

```
arr = []
for r in arr:
    print(r)
    print("Why?")
```

While it's understandable that `arr` is empty, therefore `print(r)` will return nothing, why the following piece of code does not work?

Does `for` also tests for `boolean`?

Comment: "...why the following piece of code does not work?" Where's the code?

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: `for` loops to every item in the iterable you've called, so not any one

Comment: What did you expect a loop over an empty sequence to *do*? `arr` is a list, it is iterated over, and because the list is empty it just ends right there without running the loop body.

Comment: `print(r)` doesn't technically return anything -- it produces a side effect wherein `r` is printed to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you understand. An attempt to iterate manually over a list:

```
In [349]: x = iter([1, 2, 3])

In [350]: next(x)
Out[350]: 1

In [351]: next(x)
Out[351]: 2

In [352]: next(x)
Out[352]: 3

In [353]: next(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-353-5e4e57af3a97> in <module>()
----> 1 next(x)

StopIteration:
```

Meanwhile, an empty list throws a `StopIteration` immediately:

```
In [354]: x = iter([])

In [355]: next(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-355-5e4e57af3a97> in <module>()
----> 1 next(x)

StopIteration:
```

This exact thing happens in the `for` loop, iterating over each element until a `StopIteration` exception is reached. If you have an empty list, you have nothing to iterate over:

```
In [356]: for i in [1, 2, 3]:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     
1
2
3

In [357]: for i in []:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:
```

Comment: Nice explain as always, the best! plus one ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the use of for, it goes through all the elements of the array, and what you tell it to do, if the array is empty, it doesn't executes anything, and the variable r is not used, look:

```
arr = []
for r in arr:
    print(r)
    print("Why?")
```

Doesn't print anything, instead

```
arr = [2]
for r in arr:
    print(r)
    print("Why?")
```

prints:

> 2
>
> why?

why? because, it has an element to go through

Comment: @Vinícius Aguiar thanks for the editing!

Comment: I've already returned the favour. :)

Comment: @DamianLattenero you’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The `for loop` iterates over all the objects in the iterable (in this case `arr`).

Since there are no objects in arr so the for loop will not have an object to refer to and it will reach the end of the array before entering the loop, thus finishing the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop simply iterates over whatever it is given. If the iterable that is being iterated over is empty, then the for loop will never run. Thus, the body will never be executed.

The normal for loop

```
for var in []:
    print(var)
```

is basically syntactic sugar for this

```
iterator = iter([])
while True:
    try:
        var = next(iterator)
        print(var)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

That is essentially what Python is doing behind the scenes. It creates an iterator from what is passed in, and continues to ask for the next element from the iterator until it is exhausted and a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

Since the iterable above is empty, on the first attempt Python makes to get an element from the iterator, it raises a `StopIteration`. Thus, Python skips the body of the loop, and goes to the `except` clause, which breaks the loop. The same behavior happens in your example. A `StopIteration` is immediately raised because `arr` is empty, so the for loop body is never executed.

Here is an example to further demonstrate this:

```
>>> arr = []
>>> iterator = iter(arr)
>>> next(iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    next(iterator)
StopIteration
>>>
```

As you can see, the first call to `next()` causes a `StopIteration` exception to be raised. This is the same thing that happens in your for loop body.